# Where does the Taz say that beer gives us life?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, liquor-beer, quotations, acharonim

There is a Taz on the topic of *yoshon* (old grain) that says something to the effect of:

> כי עיקר חיינו תלוי בשכר

While it's an awesome quote out of context, the basic pretense is that since the water might be toxic where they lived, he permitted the drinking of beer despite the concern of *yoshon*. I just can't seem to find the actual source, but I know that it exists. Any help with this?

Comment: The Taz meant that this was a staple of their diet, not that they had to drink beer because the water was unsafe (which seems to be a myth: http://history.stackexchange.com/a/12755).

Comment: @Fred Thanks for that info! Didn't know that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taz Yoreh Deah 293 ([s'if kattan 4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6812)):

> דחייו של אדם תלוי בשתית שכר