# What is the Torah preferred beer recommendation?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

As has already been noted in a [previous question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69634/4794), beer is a basic necessity for answering some questions.

I was wondering, have our holy Sages given us any guidance about specific brands, flavors, or types of beer that are preferred or to be avoided?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Beer Sheva, anyone?

Comment: There was a brand called שושן popular in Persia some time ago.

Comment: _stam_ someone came through and downvoted everything?

Answer (score 8):

Tehillim 123

> רבת שבעה לה נפשנו הלעג השאננים הבוז לגאי יונים
>
> Fully sated is our soul with the mockery of the complacent ones, with the booze of the arrogant.

Thus we should not purchase booze, ie, beer, from arrogant people.

Answer (score 8):

A couple basic guidelines:

The less hops the better, as hops are the mouth of injustice (Tehillim 107:42):

> וְכָל-עַוְלָה, קָפְצָה פִּיהָ
>
> All injustice, hops are its mouth

Imported beer seems to be a good choice, as our ancestor Rachel was consoled by the news that her employees were bringing back beer from enemy lands (Yirmiyahu 31:15):

> מנעי קולך מבכי, ועינייך, מדמעה:  כי יש שכר לפעולתך נאום-יהוה, ושבו מארץ אויב
>
> Refrain your voice from crying and your eyes from tears, for your employees have beer, says the Lord, and they are returning from enemy lands.

Answer (score 3):

בראשית - פרק מח

טז.הַמַּלְאָךְ הַגֹּאֵל אֹתִי מִכָּל רָע יְבָרֵךְ אֶת הַנְּעָרִים וְיִקָּרֵא בָהֶם שְׁמִי וְשֵׁם אֲבֹתַי אַבְרָהָם וְיִצְחָק וְיִדְגּוּ לָרֹב בְּקֶרֶב הָאָרֶץ

The only type of fish that would live on land is a Land Shark thus this posuk is a remez that we should drink Land Shark beer in order to be blessed by Hashem

Comment: or if you prefer to say this refers to any style of beer as long is it is brewed by a lawyer who is commonly known as a shark

Answer (score 2):

On Rosh Hashanna, one should drink [Schaefer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer_Beer) beer (because it sounds like "Shofar". This is related to the "simanim" on Rosh Hashanna night, when we eat or drink foods that sound like something related to Rosh Hashanna.) if one can still find any. Schaefer's advertising slogan used to be "The one beer to have when you're having more than one."

Purim is a time when people should have more than one beer, so Schaefer beer is the preferred beer on Purim, as well.