# A source for parve lactobacillus plantarum?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation, dairy

Lactobacillus plantarum is a strain of lactic acid producing bacteria used in many food and medicine applications. Many of which are made on equipment that process chalav nachri. Some examples include beer, cheese, and probiotic medicines. What is a list of kosher parve sources for lactobacillus plantarum?

Comment: Not all halachists consider such bacteria dairy -in terms of *kashrut*- even its source is dairy (e.g. milk products).

Comment: Bacteria doesn't come from dairy. The source for bacteria is bacteria and is a living organism. That being said a lot of the lacto that I have found is either produced in a non kosher way or on dairy equipment

Comment: FYI: I searched for "lactobacillus plantarum" on the Product Search pages of OU, OK, and Star-K and came up with a total of three hits (1 OK, 2 Star-K), all of them designated "dairy."

Comment: @Dude and these living organisms (bacteria) can be extracted from dairy, like proteins etc. That's what I mean.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83682/does-sour-beer-require-certification

Comment: @Oliver even if we assume what you are saying is true that a given bacteria found found in dairy but not considered dairy the source it was found in would still have to be kosher to begin with