# Ptij: What does beer have to do with this mishna?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Baba Kamma (6:5) says-

> הַמַּדְלִיק אֶת הַגָּדִישׁ, וְהָיוּ בּוֹ כֵלִים וְדָלָקוּ. רַבִּי יְהוּדָה אוֹמֵר, יְשַׁלֵּם מַה שֶּׁבְּתוֹכוֹ. וַחֲכָמִים אוֹמְרִים, אֵינוֹ מְשַׁלֵּם אֶלָּא גָּדִישׁ שֶׁל חִטִּין אוֹ שֶׁל שְׂעֹרִים. הָיָה גְדִי כָפוּת לוֹ וְעֶבֶד סָמוּךְ לוֹ וְנִשְׂרַף עִמּוֹ, חַיָּב. עֶבֶד כָּפוּת לוֹ וּגְדִי סָמוּךְ לוֹ וְנִשְׂרַף עִמּוֹ, פָּטוּר. וּמוֹדִים חֲכָמִים לְרַבִּי יְהוּדָה בְּמַדְלִיק אֶת הַבִּירָה, שֶׁהוּא מְשַׁלֵּם כָּל מַה שֶּׁבְּתוֹכוֹ, שֶׁכֵּן דֶּרֶךְ בְּנֵי אָדָם לְהַנִּיחַ בַּבָּתִּים:
>
> One who kindled a grain stack that had vessels in it, and they burned, Rabbi Yehuda says he must pay for what was inside the stack, and the Sages say that he only pays for the stack of wheat or barely... The Sages agree with Rabbi Yehuda when he kindled the beer, that he must pay for whatever is in it, because it is common for people to place objects in houses.

This mishna is very confusing. How would one light beer on fire? What would be in the beer that burned with it? What does this beer have to do with the explanation, which talks about houses? I'd be grateful if someone could explain this to me.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I think this question [needs beer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69634/).

Answer (score 2):

The question arises from a mistranslation of בִּירָה

It does not mean beer, but capital. For example, see Esther 1:2:

> בַּיָּמִ֖ים הָהֵ֑ם כְּשֶׁ֣בֶת ׀ הַמֶּ֣לֶךְ אֲחַשְׁוֵר֗וֹשׁ עַ֚ל
>   כִּסֵּ֣א מַלְכוּת֔וֹ אֲשֶׁ֖ר בְּשׁוּשַׁ֥ן הַבִּירָֽה׃

Thus, this line means:

> מוֹדִים חֲכָמִים לְרַבִּי יְהוּדָה בְּמַדְלִיק אֶת הַבִּירָה, שֶׁהוּא מְשַׁלֵּם כָּל מַה שֶּׁבְּתוֹכוֹ, שֶׁכֵּן דֶּרֶךְ בְּנֵי אָדָם לְהַנִּיחַ בַּבָּתִּים:
>
> And the Rabbis agree to Rabbi Yehuda when the capital city is ignited that he must pay for all that is inside of it, for people normally live in houses.

One might have thought, since the people inside the houses are hidden (Tamun), the arsonist would be exempt. The Mishna teaches that since normally people live inside houses, they are not Tamun, and a city arsonist would be Chayav for all the people he killed.

Comment: why Only for capitol cities?

Comment: @Loani You're only liable for טמון in cases where it's reasonable to suspect that something is hidden inside. Why should you suspect anyone is living anywhere other than the capital?

Answer (score 1):

There is a current trend for "craft" beers made in microbreweries which is usually someone's home. Colorado and New York City / Long Island area have recently boomed with these micobreweries. So, this is what the mishna means by saying כֵּן דֶּרֶךְ בְּנֵי אָדָם לְהַנִּיחַ בַּבָּתִּים - it's common for people to leave the ingredients in the house.

And, when it says about burning the beer, it doesn't mean, necessarily the finished product, but the materials used for making the beer which not only includes the "vessels" such as the kegs and bottles and brewing pots and such, but also the barley itself - the main ingredient. So, מְשַׁלֵּם כָּל מַה שֶּׁבְּתוֹכוֹ is ambiguous - some say it means to pay for what was in the house (the microbrewery). Others say it refers to what was in the beer, i.e., the barley, water, yeasts, etc.

Comment: Is it corona beer?

Comment: @DonielF Corona is very good beer. So, don't make fun of the beer or the Mexicans that make it.